# Calculate percentage using functions

Tags: excel, function

I have an Excel workbook (Office 2010) that lists multiple different spreadsheets (offices) in our organization.  We use this workbook to keep track of their "errors" in turned-in documents (example only).  I'm trying to figure out a good way to determine, through automation (functions) the percentage of documents that have had errors in them.  I want to determine the percentage of documents looked at versus the amount of errors, completely ignoring the amount of errors.  So if I looked at 10 documents and 7 of those had at least one error, the office's percentage of errors would be 70%.

Is there any easy way to do this?

I've tried a few functions but I continue to get errors.  I show a sample sheet (one office) below.  This example is similar across multiple sheets and there is a dashboard that I would like to display all of these statistics based on offices.

```
workpaper        DISCREPENCIES          
Paper   Spelling Grammar Punctuation Total Errors/Paper 
A.36.7     1       0       1               2
A.36.8     0       1       1               2
A.36.9     0       1       0               1
A.36.10    0       0       0               0
A.36.11    1       0       0               1
A.36.12    1       1       1               3
A.36.13    2       3       0               5
A.36.14    0       0       0               0
A.36.15    0       0       0               0
A.36.16    1       1       1               3
                           Total Errors    17
                           Total Documents 10
                 Total Documents w/ errors 7
                      Percentage of Errors 70%
```

I can do all of this manually but I would like to find a way to do this across all sheets since there are a quite a few and output them to a "dashboard" that has all offices listed in rows.

Comment: Your question as listed is basically "how does one calculate a %, ever?". What I presume you intended it to be was "how do I arrange my data so that it allows for the calculation of a %?". But, we can't answer this second question without information about how your source data is actually derived.

Comment: For example - do you just need to understand the COUNT function? COUNT(E3:E12) might be all you need to see that there are 10 documents there. Then COUNTIF(E3:E12,">0") would show how many lines have any errors at all.

Comment: Your second comment definitely helped me figure it out.  I was attempting to use the COUNTIF function but it kept erroring out on me when using the >0 because I omitted the " ".  Silly mistake but I do thank you for your help!  If you would like to "Answer" the question, I can mark yours as the answer I used.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent has covered this off nicely; you can mark his as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to look at the number of worksheets with **0** errors in them.  Then subtract that percentage from 100%.  For example in **G5**:

```
=COUNTIF(E3:E12,0)/COUNT(E3:E12)
```

and in **G6**:

```
=100%-G5
```

[image]